# Finding unique elements from the list of given numbers

Tags: python, list

I have written a code which finds unique elements from the list of integers.

```
def Distinct(arr, n):

    for i in range(0, n):

        d = 0
        for j in range(0, i):
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]):
                d = 1
                break

        if (d == 0):
            print(arr[i], end=',')
    

n = int(input('Enter length of numbers: '))
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    a = input('enter the number: ')
    arr.append(a)
print(Distinct(arr, n))
```

if my given input array is `[1,2,2,3,4]` where `n = 5` i get the output as `1,2,3,4,None` but i want the output to be `1,2,3,4`
can anyone tell how to fix this ?

Comment: `print(list(set(arr)))`

Comment: or `print(list(dict.fromkeys(arr)))` if order matters

Comment: but i don't want the output as a list

Comment: don't you know how to iterate over a list and print its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function Distinct has no `return` statement so it will always return `None`. When you call `print(Distinct(arr, n))` this is printing the `None` that is returned. You can simply remove the `print()` like so:

```
Distinct(arr, n)
```

To remove the last comma you can't print a comma on the first iteration, then print the commas before the items. This is because you don't know which item will be the last one.

```
if d == 0 and i == 0:
    print(arr[i], end='')
elif d == 0:
    print("," + arr[i], end='')
```

Comment: can you tell how to remove the end comma ?

Comment: @RAKSHITHARSH I editted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def Distinct(arr, n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]):
                lst.append(arr[i])
                break
    print(*lst, sep=',')
    

n = int(input('Enter length of numbers: '))
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    a = input('enter the number: ')
    arr.append(a)
Distinct(arr, n)
```

So first you compute all the numbers, and only at the end you print them